# C++ Accelerator keys do not work

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, accelerator

I am having trouble getting Accelerators to work.  I am using C++.

After my window is setup and shown.

```
MENUITEMINFOW mAbout;
mAbout.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
mAbout.fMask  = MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_ID;
mAbout.wID    = (UINT) ID_ABOUT;
mAbout.fType  = MFT_STRING;
mAbout.dwTypeData = (LPWSTR)L"&About";

InsertMenuItemW(HelpMenu,   0, TRUE, &mAbout);
```

My menu is working just fine, and calls my "About" box, no issue there.

Now, before the message loop, I load the accelerators:

```
// Load accelerators.
 HACCEL hAccelerators = LoadAcceleratorsW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDR_ACCELERATOR));
```

Then my main message loop:

```
while(GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    if (! TranslateAcceleratorW(msg.hwnd, hAccelerators, &msg)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
}
```

My WndProc Message handle (Again, works from the menu)

```
case WM_COMMAND: {
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == 0) {
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 101) {
            testDialog(hInstance ,hWnd,(LPSTR)"Testing");
        }
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_ABOUT) {
            DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTDIALOG), hWnd, &AboutDialogProc);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

My resource.rc file:

```
//
// Accelerator resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
IDR_ACCELERATOR ACCELERATORS
{
    "a",    ID_ABOUT, VIRTKEY, ALT
}
```

and my resource.h file:

```
#define IDR_ACCELERATOR                         122
#define ID_ABOUT                                401
```

And... well, Alt-a does not bring up the about box.  I have walked all over the Microsoft
Website, and was vary careful, but I can't find anything glaring I am doing different.

I am on Windows 7 (64bit) using MinGW and compiling in the application for Unicode.

Everything else works but this, what am I missing???

Comment: Could there be some #include I don't have that is also required to get accelerators to work?  What else could I be missing??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646373(v=vs.85).aspx

> To differentiate the message that this function sends from messages sent by menus or controls, the high-order word of the wParam parameter of the WM_COMMAND or WM_SYSCOMMAND message contains the value 1.

This was the issue, I was checking wParam for a value of 0, I didn't catch that it is `1` if sent by `TranslateAcceleratorW`

```
if (HIWORD(wParam) == 0) {
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 101) {
        testDialog(hInstance ,hWnd,(LPSTR)"Testing");
    }
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_ABOUT) {
        DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTDIALOG), hWnd, &AboutDialogProc);
        return 0;
    }
} else if (HIWORD(wParam) == 1) {    // Accelerator input 
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_ABOUT) {
        DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTDIALOG), hWnd, &AboutDialogProc);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Geeze, that was a tiny detail.

Answer (score -1):

in your resource.rc, try to remove VIRTKEY.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to put 0x41 instead of "a" in your .rc
It's the ascii code for 'A' (uppercase...)

Comment: No Dice........  I have tried combinations of both suggestions so far.  I really could use a working example of all this.... /sigh